# Modifying Database Data with PHP DOM (enclosing in tags)

Tags: php, html, dom

I have many articles, divided into sections, stored in a database. Each section consists of a section tag, followed by a header (h2) and a primary div. Some also have subheaders (h3). The raw display looks something like this:

```
<section id="ecology">
  <h2 class="Article">Ecology</h2>
  <div class="Article">
    <h3 class="Article">Animals</h3>
```

I'm using the following DOM script to add some classes, ID's and glyphicons:

```
$i = 1; // initialize counter
// initialize DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($Content); // load the markup

$sections = $dom->getElementsByTagName('section'); // get all section tags
if($sections->length > 0) { // if there are indeed section tags inside
// work on each section
foreach($sections as $section) { // for each section tag

    $section->setAttribute('data-target', '#b' . $i); // set id for section tag
    // get div inside each section

    foreach($section->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
        if($h2->getAttribute('class') == 'Article') { // if this div has class maindiv
            $h2->setAttribute('id', 'a' . $i); // set id for div tag
        }
    }

    foreach($section->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
        if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'Article') { // if this div   has class maindiv
            $div->setAttribute('id', 'b' . $i); // set id for div tag
        }
    }

    $i++; // increment counter
 }
}

 // back to string again, get all contents inside body
 $Content = '';
 foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
 $Content .= $dom->saveHTML($child); // convert to string and append to  the container
}
```

I'd like to modify the above code so that it places certain examples of "inner text" between tags.

For example, consider these headings:

```
<h3 class="Article">Animals</h3>
<h3 class="Article">Plants</h3>
```

I would like the DOM to change them to this:

```
<h3 class="Article"><span class="label label-default">Animals</span></h3>
<h3 class="Article"><span class="label label-default">Plants</span></h3>
```

I want to do something similar with the h2 tags. I don't yet know the DOM terminology well enough to search for good tutorials - not to mention confusion with DOM programs and jQuery. ;)

I think these are the basic functions I need to focus on, but I don't know how to plug them in:

```
$text = $data->textContent;
elementNode.textContent=string
```

Two Notes: 1) I understand I can do this with jQuery (perhaps a lot easier), but I think PHP might be better, as they say some users can have JavaScript disabled. 2) I'm using the class "Article" largely to distinguish elements I want to be styled by PHP DOM. A header with a different class, or no class at all, should not be affected by the DOM script.

Comment: One thing i would point out is that you are not accounting for the potential of  `<tag class="Article" />` to occur at multiple sub-levels. So if for example you only want to hit `section > div[class=Article]` you are currently modifying `section div[class=Article]`... not sure if this is an issue or not but you might want to take that into account as you develop this.

Comment: OK. Maybe I should give each element a unique class to serve as a handle, then.

Comment: Well also keep in mind the `class` attribute can be a list of classes, right now you are testing agains the class being EXACTLY equal to the class you are looking for, as opposed to it being one of potentially many classes :-) So having said all that you may want to look into XPath which will give you a much more specific way to filter through DOMNodes. There are also libraries that let you use CSS selectors (which then compile to xpath) like Zend_Dom_Query, SimpleHTMLDOM, and symfony/dom-crawler.